# Many to many relationship - association table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In our application we use spring boot + JPA to store the values. I have a requirement where we need to have two association tables in a many-to-many relationship and the association tables have additional attributes along with the foreign key.

Is it ok to have two association tables in a many-to-many relationship?

[image: Picture of the 4 tables in a many to many relationship]

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to have many to many relationship between the table.

Here is the link that can help:

[https://www.javatpoint.com/jpa-many-to-many-mapping](https://javabydeveloper.com/many-many-bidirectional-association/)

https://javabydeveloper.com/many-many-bidirectional-association/